# Rails change ActiveJob adapter for a single job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jobs, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activejob

I have some scheduled tasks that run jobs with a real queue service.

Now, I want to be able to run those tasks manually from a dashboard, wait for its execution, and read/process some of its outputs in a controller action. The typical case being when an admin wants to manually reload some statistics, and it's fine to stall the server for a couple secs.

Is there a way to change the ActiveJob adapter to "inline" in order to do that ? If possible I'd also like to read some artifacts generated by this job (could be instance variables, or the return value of the `perform`action).

Any way to do that ?

Sample Job

```
class TopLevelJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform
    some_iterator.each do 
      SomeNestedJob.rand.perform_later
      # There are several types of sub-jobs that can be called
      # Passing a flag param (perform vs perform_later) would be kind of annoying
    end
end

module SomeNestedJob
  class A < ApplicationJob; 
    def perform
       # May in turn spawn an other job with perform_later
    end
  end
  ...
  class Z < ApplicationJob; ...; end

  def self.rand
    [A..Z].sample
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe  "perform_now" is what you're looking for ... runs the task right away, without going in queue.

cf. ActiveJob on http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Base.html

Other than that, really, just make your "perform" have a flag ("has_whatever_output_you_have_in_mind") and use it in your perform action to trigger an output.

Comment: The problem is that my job triggers several nested jobs and it would be kinda annoying to change the code of all the nested jobs to pass such a flag. Ideally I'd like to change the configuration just for the current request (and revert it to normal afterwards) so I don't have to worry about all that.

Comment: Maybe you want to encapsulate actions in a module and call it from module. But that's going as annoying as previously mentionned.

Comment: You might define a "before" or "after" that will trigger the output when called with perform_now if it has the proper argument (match arg[x] with "--o" or "-- pdf").